# TCP Listener is not shut down completely

Tags: go, tcp, tcpserver

I have a TCP Listener that initialized as next:

```
myListener := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
```

Then am able to receive connections and process them. Then I need to close the server in order that I can reuse the same port but this is not happening, this is how am closing the tcp server:

```
myListener.Close()
```

In the client side am closing all the existent TCP connections to that server and then from the terminal I see that those connections are being close but the port is still in use by the server and listening (even when is not accepting new connections which is right according to documentation). This is how I check in the terminal:

```
netstat -an | grep 8080
```

And after close the client side connections I get this and cannot reuse the port:

```
tcp46      0      0  *.8080                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

After doing `myListener.Close()` I waited some time but in the terminal the port is still in use.

Answer (score 2):

The net.Listen function returns two parameters (Listener, error), in your example above you appear to only be capturing the Listener and not the error.

Assuming you're actually capturing it, you should check if the error is empty before you begin using the listener.

```
package main

import "net"

func main() {
    myListener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    myListener.Close() 
}
```

Something similar to the snippet above should work. Now if you're not getting an error (I presume you will get an error), the problem you likely have is that something else is already using that port.

Try running your netstat as root so you can see all processes which will give you a better idea of what is holding on to that port.

`sudo netstat -apn | grep -i listen | grep 8080`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to checking the error from the `net.Listener` as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65638937/1435495

You will also want to add a `defer` to your `myListener.Close()` will help ensure that the close does actually execute even if something would cause the app to exit prematurely.

`defer myListener.Close()`